# custom data attributes alternative?

Tags: html, xhtml

The following code is in a while loop, with values from the database.  I am storing these values in custom data attributes for jQuery.

```
<div class='pending-information' data-id='$id' data-pid='$position' data-sid='$sid' data-image='$image' data-counter='$counter' data-start='$start'></div>
```

What is the professional approach? This method won't be valid in XHTML1.  So whats the common method for storing attributes/values for jQuery?

Comment: This is the way to do it in HTML5 which is successor to both HTML4 and XHTML. So, why bother to make it XHTML conform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the professional approach?

Exactly what you are doing - `data-*` attributes are common way to do this.

> This method won't be valid in XHTML1

So what? XHTML is not going to be extended into a new version - it is HTML 5 from now on and `data-*` attributes are the way to go.